# How do I hide the icon on a TWebSplitter component?

Tags: delphi, splitter, tms-web-core

In the middle of the splitter, there's an icon:

[image: Splitter Icon]

I don't want there to be any icons on the splitter. I don't see any property to modify this.

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `GripColor` property of the `TWebSplitter` to the same value as its `Color` property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `TWebSplitter` component is actually just a `<canvas>` tag in HTML.

So you can also just reset the canvas. Assuming your component's name is "MySplitter", here's the code to remove the icon:

```
asm
  this.MySplitter.FCanvas.FContext.reset();
end;
```

And you can simply put that 3 lines of code in your `OnCreate` event.